# Appharbor share a RabbitMQ instance

Tags: rabbitmq, appharbor

Is it possible to share a RabbitMQ instance from several applications in Appharbor? That's one of the benefits with messaging. To do that I need to know the url to the RabbitMQ server and it can be read from an Appharbor configuration variable. But that's *within* an application.

How can I get the url from another app? I don't want to hardcode it because of this text on the configuration page:

"Accessing the configuration variables below should be done programatically, as the values may be updated by the add-on provider without notice."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing configuration between say a background worker and a web worker works seamlessly because the workers use the same configuration.

We're trying to figure out good ways to share add-ons between multiple apps.

Comment: It's crucial to be able to share a RabbitMQ server between apps to do proper messaging. But I have to wait then. Any time frames?

Comment: In the interrim, an option is to simply copy-paste the relevant connectioninfo from one app to the other.